# How to drop a given event in logstash based on date?

Tags: logstash

I have a Kafka JSON stream that I set as my input in logstash.

I would like to drop events for which dates are before a given date (say, today's midnight).

I can parse the input correctly (it's json, so it's default), and I can print it to stdout with the json codec.

How do I filter the date? Is there something like:

```
filter {
  if [date] <= "some date" {
    drop { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before your date{} filter, drop into ruby{} and tuck away the server's current time:

```
event['server_timestamp'] = event['@timestamp']
```

Then use your date{} filter as normal to reset @timestamp to the event's time.

After that, drop into ruby{} again to compute the difference:

```
event['lag'] = ( ( event['server_timestamp'] - event['@timestamp'] ) ).to_f
```

And back in logstash, check the lag against your constraints:

```
# seconds!
if [lag] > 60 {
     drop{}
}
```

If you don't want to compare to the server's time, you can use any time you want.  When I tried to use ruby's Datetime, it seemed to drop milliseconds, so beware of that.