# Difference between two timestamps ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elapsedtime

I want to find out the time difference between two timestamps, to be more specific I want to calculate the processing time of a transaction.
Currently I am using the "elapsed" filter which calculates the time difference between two logs events. In other words it is calculating the time difference between the time when the logs were indexed.
I want to calculate the time difference when they were published or logged

example

INFO date-time Message Event started
INFO date-time Message Event ended

Currently it's telling me the difference in between times they were indexed. What I want is

date-time (Event ended) - date-time (Event started)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop into ruby and compute it.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31418211/677561) (might need updating for latest java-based objects).